# AIX user password reset

Tags: ansible, aix

I'm able to reset password of a user in Linux using the below task. In Aix also it is executing successfully but password not getting changed and getting access denied.

```
- name: reset pw
  user:
    name: "{{ userid }}"
    update_password: always
    password: "{{ passwd | password_hash('sha512') }}"
  register: resetPwOp
```

The result as below.

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [110.110.110.115] => {
    "msg": "resetpwop: {u'comment': u'94/C/UniqueID_cor1', u'shell': u'/usr/bin/ksh', u'group': 2, u'name': u'user1', u'changed': True, 'failed': False, u'state': u'present', u'home': u'/home/user1', u'move_home': False, u'password': u'NOT_LOGGING_PASSWORD', u'append': False, u'uid': 46}"
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use commands when module is available.

Comment: Are you sure this module support AIX? Because the passwords in Linux and AIX are stored on quite different way.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the same operation with the modules developed for AIX systems.

Installation notes here:
https://github.com/IBM/ansible-power-aix/blob/dev-collection/docs/source/installation.rst

If you are using AIX 7.1-7.2 you should setup yum first to install Python2.7(in AIX 7.3 installed by default) and after you will be able to run the ibm.power_aix.user module.

Here you may find several examples:
https://github.com/IBM/ansible-power-aix/tree/dev-collection/playbooks